# DatePicker widget usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar, widget

I'm trying to put on my site this calendar widget (not as a datepicker binded to input form field but as a widget!): http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ - I've added necessary files links in the header, but widget is not displaying - here is also constructor for it (from header):

```
    <script>
        $('#date3').DatePicker({
        flat: true,
        date: ['2008-07-28','2008-07-31'],
        current: '2008-07-31',
        calendars: 3,
        mode: 'range',
        starts: 1
    });
  </script>
```

and my div in html: `<div id="date3"></div>`
I don't know if it is really good way of usage this widget - please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works [fine for me here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPwu8/) ... then only thing I have added is putting the `datepicker` initialisation inside a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //your code here
});
```

block to ensure the [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) before the datepicker is called.

Note - I added both JS and CSS files :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
```

Comment: it works now! thanks a lot.. I had also add styles to this #data3 div with minimal width and height..